# C# where to add a method

Tags: c#, methods

I'm fresh to C# - just started a day ago. I have to do a simple C# database consisting of music albums etc. The problem I got is that I can't call a method i just did, can anyone help me to include this method in main?

```
void addnew()
        {
            int ID = currid;
            string AlbNm;
            string Art;
            string RelDstring;
            int RelD;
            string TrAmnstring;
            int TrAmn;
            string Loc;
            int Rat;
            int ratswitch;
            string ratswitchstring;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj nazwe albumu");
            AlbNm = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj nazwe wykonawcy");
            Art = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj rok wydania");
            RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
            bool ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);
            bool correctyear = RelD < 2014 && RelD > 1900;
            while (ifintreld == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
                RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            RelD = Convert.ToInt32(RelDstring);
            while (correctyear == false)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj daty z zakresu 1900-2014");
            RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
            while (ifintreld == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
                RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            RelD = Convert.ToInt32(RelDstring);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj ilosc utworow");
            TrAmnstring = Console.ReadLine();
            bool ifinttramn = int.TryParse(TrAmnstring, out TrAmn);
            while (ifinttramn == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna liczbe utworow, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
                TrAmnstring = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            RelD = Convert.ToInt32(RelDstring);
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj sciezke do pliku");
            Loc = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj ocene [1-5]");
            ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
            bool ifintrat = int.TryParse(ratswitchstring, out ratswitch);
            while (ifintrat == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna ocene, uzyj liczb calkowitych z zakresu 1-5.");
                ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            ratswitch = Convert.ToInt32(ratswitchstring);
            while (ratswitch != 1 || ratswitch != 2 || ratswitch != 3 || ratswitch != 4 || ratswitch != 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna ocene, uzyj liczb calkowitych z zakresu 1-5.");
                ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
                while (ifintrat == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna ocene, uzyj liczb calkowitych z zakresu 1-5.");
                    ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Rat = ratswitch;
         }
```

VS cries for nonstatic method in static main, but with that currid and currid++ it cannot be static (at least i think so ;p)
Can anyone tell me how to run this method in my console app?

Comment: It depends on where this method is located and where you're trying to call it from. The signature is `void addNew()` which is missing the access modifier (e.g. `public`, `private`, etc.). By default, they are `internal` which is *probably* good enough, but you should be explicit. Where is your calling code?

Comment: i understand you are new but this makes my eyes bleed. Take a look at the [coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

Comment: @Jonesy Because of the rats and rat switches? Personally, I'm intrigued.

Comment: Also I think you want `if` statements for some of those.  You have several infinite loops

Comment: That's right, that's my main problem now ;/

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is all in a single "Program" class.  To solve the "static" problem, just create an instance of that class (or whatever class `addnew` is in):

```
   var p = new Program();
   p.addnew();
```

It *may* work to make `currid` static instead; the only drawback is *all* instances of `Program` would use the same `currid` variable.  Since this is just a learning exercise it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Amazing solution i didn't think about...
I know my way to get it working is bad and your eyes probably bleed, but try to understand me. I was told to provide a project 2 days ago. I have to deliver it in 3 hr and I did not get any help from my teacher bout this project...

Comment: @user3658127 Yeah you have several other things wrong with your program but that should get you going.

Comment: found few errors, much easier too look for them when you see them in console than in code :D

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create an instance of the class in which this method is located. So if the class is called TestClass, you do:

```
new TestClass().addnew();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling nonstatic method from a static method 
If you can create an instance of that class you will be able to get that method into main as a property

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your class name is Program you can use nonstatic function inside main as following

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program abc = new Program();
        abc.addnew();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to make all your variables and methods static in order to use them in the Main method, or create a new class and use the object in the Main method.