# C# how to clear a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to create simple error handling with `while` and I can't clear my string.

```
string RelDstring;
int RelD;
bool ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);
while (ifintreld != true)
{
    RelDstring = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
    RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
}
RelD = Convert.ToInt32(RelDstring);
```

It's just infinite loop as if my `string` was incorrect all the time. How can I clear my string?

Comment: You never set the `ifintreld` variable back to true.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger.  Step through the program and see what's happening on each line, one at a time.  The problem should be fairly obvious by the second iteration.

Comment: Move TryParse inside the while loop. As well pointed out by Servy, Debugger is your best programming buddy!

Comment: Would also love to know how to get it to work "line by line". Can't really find an answer.

Comment: `ifintreld` is only set once.

Comment: @user3658127 your code as shown won't compile - you need to copy over more of your _actual_ code to get good answers.

Comment: You don't need to use a loop. See my answer.

Comment: BTW  ... `while (ifintreld != true)` and `if (ifintreld != true)` should be written `while(!ifintreld )` or `if(ifintreld)`. Since `ifintreld` is a boolean value the way it's written is like saying if false == true.  Just saying.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `TryParse` within the loop to see if the input is valid after the retry:

```
string RelDstring;
int RelD;

Console.WriteLine("Podaj rok wydania");
RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();        // copied from previous question

bool ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);
while (ifintreld != true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
    RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
    ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);
}
```

Also:

- you don't need to set the string to `null`
- you don't need to parse again *after* the while loop

Comment: You are declaring the `ifintreld` variable twice

Comment: Yep, the 4 downvotes are most intriguing. I was about to post almost this exact text.

Comment: As far as I understand, first `bool ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);` will prevent code compilation in this code, since `RelDstring` is not initialized.

Comment: do..while would be more appropriate

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov If you look at the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768457/c-sharp-where-to-add-a-method) you'll see that `RelDstring` _is_ initialized - the OP just didn;t copy that part over to this question.

Comment: @Edin not for a "retry" loop - the message would be different after the first try.

Comment: Do you need a variable for `ifintreld`, can't you just use the `Int32.TryParse()` as the condition for the while loop?

Answer (score 3):

You should change bool variable `ifintreld`. String is not checked in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
string RelDstring;
int RelD;
bool ifintreld;

RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);

while(!ifintreld)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
    RelDstring = Console.ReadLine();
    ifintreld = int.TryParse(RelDstring, out RelD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after having to google translate this, You can do this instead. I assume you are just validating the user entered a valid year. There is no reason to loop this.

```
string year = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime validYear;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(year, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out validYear))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Year");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string relDstring;
int relD;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Podano bledny rok wydania, uzyj liczb calkowitych.");
    relDstring = Console.ReadLine();
} while(!int.TryParse(relDstring, out relD);
```